# Perpendicular Lines.

Tags: 3d

If two lines $L_1$ and $L_2$ in space, are defined by:
$$L_1=\{x=\sqrt{\lambda}y+(\sqrt{\lambda}-1)\\z=(\sqrt{\lambda}-1)y+\sqrt{\lambda}\}\text{ and }\\L_2=\{x=\sqrt{\mu}y+(1-\sqrt{\mu})\\z=(1-\sqrt{\mu})y+\sqrt{\mu}\}$$
then $L_1$ is perpendicular to $L_2$, forall non-negative reals $\lambda$ and $\mu$, such that:
It can be easily seen:
$$L_1:\frac{x-(\sqrt{\lambda}-1)}{\sqrt{\lambda}}=\frac{y}{1}=\frac{z-\sqrt{\lambda}}{(\sqrt{\lambda}-1)}\\
L_2:\frac{x-(1-\sqrt{\mu})}{\sqrt{\mu}}=\frac{y}{1}=\frac{z-\sqrt{\mu}}{(1-\sqrt{\mu})}\\
$$
So dot product (of those) must be zero:
$$\sqrt{\lambda}\sqrt{\mu}+1+(\sqrt{\lambda}-1)(1-\sqrt{\mu})=0\\
\sqrt\lambda+\sqrt\mu=0\\
\lambda=\mu=0$$
Options given are:
$$\lambda=\mu,\lambda\ne\mu,\sqrt\lambda+\sqrt\mu=1,\lambda+\mu=0$$
It seems three of them are correct but only one is actually correct.

Comment: Perhaps it's only me, but I don't understand how you're defining $\;L_i\;$ . As far as I know, a line in space is given in the form $$(a,b,c)+t(p,q,r)\;,\;\;t\in\Bbb R$$

Comment: @Timbuc your's vector form. Don't you know 3d co-ordinate geometry (mine one is that)?

Comment: @AD I thought I did, but *any* other form I know is equivalente to the above one: you can also give $\;x,y,z\;$ in parametric form, say...I still can't understand what you did.

Comment: Oh, I think I missed those $\;y$'s there and some curly parentheses! Let me check. It's just that, for some reason, you jumped down line at the midst of the parentheses...!

Comment: @Timbuc see http://www.netcomuk.co.uk/~jenolive/vect17.html

Comment: LOL @ADG...yes, **that** I know, but some how the jumping in the middle of the parentheses confused me.

Comment: @Timbuc (x,y,z)=(a,b,c)+t(p,q,r) $\iff$ (x-a)/p=(y-b)/q=(z-c)/r (=t) Elimiates t. Firstmost is a modified form of this and the afterwards one are purely this form. Timbuc? R u there?

Comment: I already got that, after I made sense of those broken line. Read my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me see: the lines are

$$L_1 \;:\;\;\left\{\;\left(\;x=\sqrt\lambda\,y+\sqrt\lambda-1\,,\,\,y\,,\,\,z=(\sqrt\lambda-1)y+\sqrt\lambda\;\right)\right\}=$$

$$=\left(\sqrt\lambda-1\,,\,\,0\,,\,\,\sqrt\lambda\right)+t\left(\sqrt\lambda\,,\,\,1\,,\,\,\sqrt\lambda-1\right)\;,\;\;t\in\Bbb R$$

$$L_2\;:\;\;\left\{\;\left(\;x=\sqrt\mu\,y+1-\sqrt\lambda\,,\,\,y\,,\,\,z=(1-\sqrt\mu)y+\sqrt\mu\;\right)\right\}=$$

$$=\left(1-\sqrt\mu\,,\,0\,,\,\,\sqrt\mu\right)+t\left(\sqrt\mu\,,\,1\,,\,1-\sqrt\mu\right)$$

Thus, $\;L_1\perp L_2\iff\;$ their direction vectors are perpendicular, iff

$$0=\left(\sqrt\lambda\,,\,\,1\,,\,\,\sqrt\lambda-1\right)\cdot\left(\sqrt\mu\,,\,1\,,\,1-\sqrt\mu\right)=\sqrt{\lambda\mu}+1+\sqrt\lambda-\sqrt{\lambda\mu}-1+\sqrt\mu\iff$$

$$\iff\sqrt\lambda=-\sqrt\mu$$

Comment: so which option out of four do you see as correct?

Comment: Of the four you wrote in the bottom of the question? None, of course...but I am now wondering whether you meant to write $$x=\sqrt\lambda\,y+(\sqrt\lambda-1)z+\ldots$$and not what I wrote in my answer. You *really* should **not** break definitions that way and jump lines!